# Library .js file getting corrupted

Tags: 8, javascript

I'm trying to get [views slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) to run on a Drupal 8 site. I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/drupal-8-slideshows/) and have downloaded the required libraries. I've set up the view, and it shows up fine on a page when it's included, however it will not cycle.

I checked my inspector window and found I was getting errors each time that the slide tried to advance:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).cycle is not a function

jquery.cycle is one of the required libraries that I installed. So I switched off the javascript aggregation to make sure jquery.cycle was being loaded in. It is, but it looks like it's corrupted:

[image: Screen shot of corrupted file]

I tried to delete jquery.cycle.all.js and reinstall, but it seems to be doing the same thing. It also only seems to do this when the cache-busting bit is added on the end (/libraries/jquery.cycle/jquery.cycle.all.js?v=3.0.3 is bad, but /libraries/jquery.cycle/jquery.cycle.all.js loads perfectly fine)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think it is a bit of a long shot, but do you have the CHARSET metatag in use? You may want to try adding the charset attribute to the script tag calling the library - <script src="myscripts.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

Comment: Did you find any solution to this @Jance? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: No, I never did, I ended up switching modules and going with slick instead.